# Tosca puzzle 81121 solved with RBFW (again and again)

Tags: automation, automated-tests, robotframework, puzzle

This range/series is about test automation. The show the CEO's and managers of this world (in a later moment when all work is done) what exactly the difference is between Tosca and f.e. RobotFrameWork.

The results will be on Youtube just like FlurFunk did with Tosca. ( https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCR5i6k5emJ6hxox-iQcv85Q )

But in some cases I get stuck and I need some help from the community.

This puzzle is about clicking a button until the name changes
https://obstaclecourse.tricentis.com/Obstacles/81121

What I got so far is:

```
 *** Settings ***
# https://robotframework-browser.org/
Library   Browser
Library    String
#Library  Tables
#Title is:  AGAIN AND AGAIN

*** Variables ***
@{LIST}   | CLICK ME | LICK ME |

*** Test Cases ***
Example Test 70310
    Browser.OPEN BROWSER  https://obstaclecourse.tricentis.com/Obstacles/81121
    CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
    CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
    ${element}=  GET TEXT    //*[@id="button"] 
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{LIST}
        ${element}=  GET TEXT    //*[@id="button"] 
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    //*[@id="button"]
        #CONTINUE FOR LOOP IF    ${element} != 'ENOUGH'
    LOG TO CONSOLE    1
    END
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{LIST}
        ${element}=  GET TEXT    //*[@id="button"] 
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    //*[@id="button"]
        #CONTINUE FOR LOOP IF    ${element} != 'ENOUGH'
    LOG TO CONSOLE    2
    END
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{LIST}
        ${element}=  GET TEXT    //*[@id="button"] 
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    //*[@id="button"]
        #CONTINUE FOR LOOP IF    ${element} != 'ENOUGH'
    LOG TO CONSOLE    3
    END
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{LIST}
        ${element}=  GET TEXT    //*[@id="button"] 
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    //*[@id="button"]
        #CONTINUE FOR LOOP IF    ${element} != 'ENOUGH'
    LOG TO CONSOLE    4
    END
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{LIST}
        ${element}=  GET TEXT    //*[@id="button"] 
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    //*[@id="button"]
        #CONTINUE FOR LOOP IF    ${element} != 'ENOUGH'
    LOG TO CONSOLE    5
    END
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{LIST}
        ${element}=  GET TEXT    //*[@id="button"] 
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    //*[@id="button"]
        #CONTINUE FOR LOOP IF    ${element} != 'ENOUGH'
    LOG TO CONSOLE    6
    END
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{LIST}
        ${element}=  GET TEXT    //*[@id="button"] 
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    //*[@id="button"]
        #CONTINUE FOR LOOP IF    ${element} != 'ENOUGH'
    LOG TO CONSOLE    7
    END
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{LIST}
        ${element}=  GET TEXT    //*[@id="button"] 
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    //*[@id="button"]
        #CONTINUE FOR LOOP IF    ${element} != 'ENOUGH'
    LOG TO CONSOLE    8
    END
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{LIST}
        ${element}=  GET TEXT    //*[@id="button"] 
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    //*[@id="button"]
        #CONTINUE FOR LOOP IF    ${element} != 'ENOUGH'
    LOG TO CONSOLE    9
    END
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{LIST}
        ${element}=  GET TEXT    //*[@id="button"] 
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    xpath=/html/body/section/div/div/h3
        CLICK    //*[@id="button"]
        #CONTINUE FOR LOOP IF    ${element} != 'ENOUGH'
    LOG TO CONSOLE    10
    END
    Get Text         xpath=//body    *=   You solved this automation problem.
    # used resources  https://robocorp.com/docs/languages-and-frameworks/robot-framework/for-loops
```

but I'm pretty sure this is not the full correct way how to do it.

So the question here is: how can I get to the result without re-using the For loop 10 times in the code?

Why is this:

```
CONTINUE FOR LOOP IF    ${element} != 'ENOUGH'
```

resulting into this: Evaluating expression 'CLICK ME != 'ENOUGH'' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 1)

Comment: error message solution: CONTINUE FOR LOOP IF    "${element}" != "ENOUGH"

Comment: A loop with two iterations reused 10 times in the code == a single loop with 20 iterations -  there you are ;)